# How to run pyautogui on mac?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyautogui

I simply tried to run a code by importing `pyautogui` module, using the `position` function.
However, every time, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rahulbansal/Desktop/gfg/try.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 241, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/Users/rahulbansal/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 100, in <module>
    from rubicon.objc import ObjCClass, CGPoint
  File "/Users/rahulbansal/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/rubicon/objc/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .runtime import (  # noqa: F401
  File "/Users/rahulbansal/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/rubicon/objc/runtime.py", line 785
    self.restype, *self.argtypes = ctypes_for_method_encoding(self.encoding)
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please share a minimal, reproducible example of code for your problem.

Comment: Unrelated, but if, as it seems, you are just starting a new project, you really should not be using Python v2.7. It is obsolete, Python 3 has been out 10 years or so.

Comment: Speaking of which, it looks like you may be trying to use the Python 3 version of `pyautogui` from a Python 2 script.

Comment: Hello, this error is probably explained and solved [in this github issue](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/426).